# Data search optimization

Tags: elasticsearch, optimization, data-structures

I have such a elastic index with fields:

type - this field hold information about film type in this case it is serial

season - number of serial season

episode - number of episode in season

rate  - rate for that episode

timestamp - date of creation of record

I have such a problem to solve:

I want to create new future for user that he could follow the serial progress. So I need to have the information about watched episodes. The information that episode is watched is represented by above record with rate.

For example:
The serial has 10 seasons and each of seasons has 10 episodes. User has watched  s1e1, s1e2, s1e5. Do you have any idea what is the best way to hold such a information?  Without checking whole elastic index and checking if there is vote on episode? Maybe create another structure or add more fields to above index?

Answer (score 0):

I would create a new record for each episode/season that the user has watched, the do a [rollup](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/8.4/rollup-overview.html) on the episode records to create a season records that contains the sum of things